# Mean Value of Path on the 3-Sphere defined by the Combination of Two Rotations

Tags: geometry, rotations, means

Suppose that we have a unit quaternion on $q_a\in S^3\subset\mathbb{H}$ and a quaternion that defines a circle on the 3-sphere $q_z(\zeta)\in S^3\subset\mathbb{H}$, where $\zeta\in[0,2\pi]$. Suppose, for the sake of a pedagogical example, that $q_z(\zeta)=(\cos\zeta,\hat{\mathbf{z}}\sin\zeta)$. How do we find the mean of the path on the 3-sphere defined by the variation of $\zeta$, corresponding to the rotation of the reference frame? Taking the normal mean value $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}q_aq_z(\zeta)d\zeta$ gives us an answer off of the path. This should be related in some intuitive way to the SLERP operation, but SLERP defines a different path between $q_a$ and $q_aq_z(\zeta)$: $\int_0^{1}\frac{\sin[(1-t)\arccos(q_a\cdot q_z(\pi))]}{\sin[\arccos(q_a\cdot q_z(\pi))]}q_a+\frac{\sin[t\arccos(q_a\cdot q_z(\pi))]}{\sin[\arccos(q_a\cdot q_z(\pi))]}q_aq_z(\pi)dt$, the average along half the path defined using SLERP, differs at its halfway point: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q_a + q_aq_z(\pi))\neq q_aq_z(\frac{\pi}{2})$. Any hints as to take the spherical mean on an arbitrary path of the sphere (which is not necessarily a circle)?

Comment: If your path has an arc-length-preserving symmetry under the antipodal map, then the mean must surely be undefined (just as the mean point of the equator on the earth's surface is undefined).  Also, I don't see how $q_a$ (is that different from $q_A$?) enters into the two sentences you wrote that are actually questions.

Comment: @John Thinking more clearly after my coffee, and yeah, the mean should be undefined here, since we're considering a full elliptical path. $q_A$ should've been $q_a$, teaching me to not submit stack exchange questions in the morning. For the sake of people maybe vaguely looking up this question, I'll leave the question up: the question still stands for paths where $\zeta$ is in some proper closed subset of $[0,2\pi]$, so I will edit the question accordingly.